# pre-compile asp.net MVC web site in TFS 2010 build server

Tags: tfs, continuous-deployment, precompile

I have set up continuous deployment process for asp.net MVC project using TFS 2010 build server. I am using “FlieCopy” to copy web site contents to shared path. Following are my MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder 
/p:_PackageTempDir=\\sharedPath  /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

Now I want to pre-compile the site before copying it to shared path. With web-deploy there is an option to opt for pre-compiled binaries. On similar lines, can I instruct build server to pre-compile the site and then copy it to the shared path? If yes, which parameter will I need to add in the MSBuild argument?

Comment: What process template are you using? The Upgrade Template (which runs MSBuild) or the Default Template?

Comment: I am using the Default Template.

Comment: Actually, `DeployOnBuild` should be enough to invoke the aspnet_compiler. If you look in your logs, are you seeing any aspnet_compiler errors? Try adding `/p:Configuration=Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aspnet_compiler` for this. for detailed information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(v=vs.80).aspx

I'm using it to build my website using jenkins

Update: My command line

```
aspnet_compiler -nologo -v / -p . -u -f -d T:\Publish\WebSite
```

It compiles all code and copies binaries and contents to target folder. I run this under web folder hence `-p .`. It is a MVC3 web application. You do not specifically need to us MSBuild.

Comment: From command prompt I use “aspnet_compiler” command to get the pre-compiled binaries. But I don’t know how to use this command while building the site using TFS 2010 build server. I am looking for a way to tell build server to pre-compile the binaries through MSBuild Arguments.